# How to disable or remove multibranch pipeline trigger on existing jobs

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have hundreds of jenkins jobs(multibranch pipeline) with trigger enabled to periodically scan respective repositories every 5 mins. I'm trying to disable "scan multibranch pipeline triggers" on all the existing jobs in a particular folder(development/microservice). I'm running below script from Jenkins script console and getting exception at removeTrigger

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.triggers.*
import jenkins.model.*
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder
for (it in Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.class)) {
  if(it.fullName.length() > 25 && it.fullName.substring(0,25) == 
  'development/microservice/' && it.fullName.split("/").length == 3) {
    println it.fullName  
    it.triggers.each { descriptor, trigger -> 
            it.removeTrigger(descriptor)
            it.save()
          }
    }
 }
```

Can someone please help me how to disable triggers on multibranch pipeline jobs programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

It seems one just needs to iterate over the triggers, and pass the right part to `removeTrigger()`; that means passing the **trigger** rather than the **descriptor**:

```
for (p in Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.class)) {
  p.triggers.each { descriptor, trigger ->
    //println descriptor
    //println trigger
    p.removeTrigger(trigger)
  }
}
```

Output sample for a single trigger, when `println` statements are not commented out:

```
com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger$DescriptorImpl@30f35b28
com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger@3745f994
```

Many thanks for your question, your almost working code helped me a lot. `;)`